# use .Contains() in linq.js

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am using linq.js to filter a JSON object `filteredRegionList`. I have a property in my object named `dimRegionID`and an array `regionList` containing regionID's. Now I want to filter `filteredRegionList` for`dimRegionID` present in 
`regionList`. I am using the below mentioned code for the same.

```
JSON.parse(Enumerable.From(filteredRegionList)
                            .Where(function (x) { return Enumerable.From(filteredObj).Contains(x.dimRegionID) })
                            .Select(function (x) { return x; }).ToJSON());
```

This is not working for me. Could any one please tell me what mistake I am doing in the where clause.

Comment: If my answer is not the issue then could you elaborate a little bit more on your question, what is "not working", and are you getting any results back, or is it not filtering, are you getting some sort of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your filtering by the wrong array, you specified in your question that your trying to filter by "regionList", but you actually filtering by "filteredObj":

```
JSON.parse(Enumerable.From(filteredRegionList)
    .Where(function (x) { return Enumerable.From(regionList).Contains(x.dimRegionID) })
    .ToJSON());
```

Comment: It was my bad...I got confused between the several arrays I was using...Your answer is correct